# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql

I am receiving the following `error`:

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I only get this on my `production server`. On my `localhost` I do not receive the `error`. The logins for the user is the same on both. The `code` is just pushed to the `server`. I have the `username` and `password` both supplied. Same databases and both trying to connect to `'localhost'`. Both servers run PHP 5.6

There is no difference between the `production` and `test server`, besides the fact I am only getting the `error` on my `production server`. I have restarted and re-added the database and `user` to the `MySQL server`.

I would please like help on this as I have not found someone have this same issue, usually it is someone who forgot something or wrote 'bad code'. Well, this is different since mine 'sometimes' works, just not on my `production server`.

Code in my `class file`:

```
public function connect($hostname, $database, $username, $password, $port = 3306)
    {
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$database;host=$hostname;port=$port;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            print "MySQL Error:" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
            die('');
        }
    }
```

Code in the php file causing the `error`

```
$db = new db;
$db->connect('localhost', 'DATABASE', 'USER', 'PASS');
```

Comment: "I have the username and password both supplied." "(using password: NO)" Either you or the computer is lying.

Comment: Maybe you dont have accessible your localhost from the Internet. Can you ping your localhost from that server? If it is possible...

Comment: Localhost is the server. Both servers have an identical database to one another that the website is trying to connect to. Only it is failing on one but not the other.